# Configure Active Directory on Windows 7

Tags: active-directory, windows-7, ad-lds

I am to configuring Active Directory on Windows 7. I have followed this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9081888/active-directory-server-on-windows-7) and installed AD LDS.

But i am unable to create a new user in the active directory.

Also, I am able to browse the existing directory in the network, but i want to create a new directory and admin user in it. And then create the users to that new directory.

I am not sure if it is achievable or if it is how can i?

**Edit**: I want help in creating Admin user with a new AD Database to play with ad in java code

Comment: AD LDS is not a "full" Active Directory. You need a real Windows Server OS for that. What are you actually trying to do? Can you please explain a little further?

Comment: @MichelZ please check my edit

Comment: @DownVoters why downvote? can you please comment?

Comment: @user549757 "This question does not show any research effort; it is unclear or not useful" - also, per the Close-reasons: Off-topic because it does not pertain to Professional System Administration

Comment: @user549757 This is still not a "real" Active Directory. It's a "Lightweight Directory Service" (LDAP). Have a read [here](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc733064.aspx) If you still want to continue with AD LDS, have a read [here](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc772194.aspx) on how to create a user

Answer (score 4):

### No - it is not achievable

The premise for "running" Active Directory Domain Services is a Domain Controller - a server role only available in Windows Server, not in the client editions of Windows